# Escape characted within a sting with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with my script with the following var:

```
var jsondatacats = eval(currentbtn.attr("data-jsond"));
```

it worked well, until data-json attr got a string where one of the values contained a single quote "How-to's".

[image]

Going forward I'll make sure my PHP catches this, but at the moment I'm wondering if I could address this issue and stop JS script from throwing an error with a JS solution.

Is it possible?

Comment: Don't use `eval()`. If the `data-jsond` attribute value is JSON, use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: What are some example of this attribute value? How is it set in your HTML?

Comment: There's not a whole lot you can do about existing values that are not formatted properly. Going forward you should use `json_encode()` (in PHP) or `JSON.stringify()` (in JavaScript) to fill in the attribute. Also, if you use jQuery's `.data()` method, it will automatically parse JSON.

Comment: @Phil, thanks for the suggestion. I've tried JSON.parse() but now I'm getting a different error: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 column 749 of the JSON data"

Comment: @Phil I've updated my post with the real life example.

Comment: Where's the end of the attribute value?

Comment: @Phil -- added the screenshot. For some reason dev tools converted all quotes when I pasted.

Comment: That's just what dev-tools does. It makes encoded values readable. Your HTML source code will be the source of truth

Comment: Makes sense. I've updated from source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to take a guess here that you are using something like this in your PHP script

```html
<i data-jsond='<?= json_encode($someVariable) ?>'></i>
```

The issue here is that any single-quotes in the JSON output will prematurely end your attribute value. The same would happen if you used double-quotes around the attribute value.

When injecting values into HTML, always make sure you encode them correctly. For example

```html
<i data-jsond="<?= htmlspecialchars(json_encode($someVariable)) ?>"></i>
```

This will produce something like the following which is parseable as JSON

```js
const jsonData = $('#currentButton').data('jsond')
// or jsonData = JSON.parse($('#currentButton').attr('data-jsond'))
$.each(jsonData, function(key, val) { 
  console.info(key, ':', val)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<i id="currentButton" data-jsond="{&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Hello 'world'&quot;}"></i>
```

Comment: Lemme give it a whirl

Comment: I now get another error: TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in '[{"id":"140593",... I've updated my OP with the full function. Now the error shifted to $.each line.

Comment: You still seem to be using `eval()`. Like I said earlier, don't do that

Comment: That's the original function. I've changed since to have JSON.parse() but the error shifted down to $.each

Comment: OK, I think I got it. I also added JSON.parse(jsondataformergedcats) in $.each and everything seems to be working now. Phew... Thanks for your help!